# Firebase Object to array on my Angular4 app

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Im trying to use *ngFor in my app to loop through my database to get data from each PostId

This is how its pushed into my firebase database

```js
 create(post) {
    return this.db.list('/posts').push(post);
  }
```

this is how I get it from my database

```js
 get(postId) {
    return this.db.object('/posts/' + postId);
  }
```

This is how its stored in my firebase database

```js
"posts" : {
    "-L4mKOzN9UZ3ls10ED5h" : {
      "body" : "Pureed squash and sweet potatoes are some of the handiest ingredients to have around your kitchen in the fall and winter months. .",
      "imageUrl" : "https://32lxcujgg9-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/butternut-Squash-Blue-Cheese-Pizza-8.jpg",
      "name" : "tolulope",
      "title" : "Butternut Squash Pizza with Blue Cheese"
    }
  },
```

this is how I'm trying to use it in my HTML

```html
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let post of post$ | async">
      <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
          <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight waves-light" mdbRippleRadius>
               <img src="{{ post.imageUrl }}" alt="First sample image">
               <a>
                <div class="mask"></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the below is the error message

> Error trying to diff 'tolulope'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: you are trying to iterate on single object, not array or iterable collection

Comment: I'm actually trying to get that particular data through the postId

Comment: Posts object is not an array. It's just an object. You can't iterate over an object.

Comment: are you trying to show all posts in template?

Comment: just that particular post @Hareesh

Answer (score 0):

Check out following code snippet.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  posts = `{
    "posts": {
        "-L4mKOzN9UZ3ls10ED5h": {
            "body": "Pureed squash and sweet potatoes are some of the handiest ingredients to have around your kitchen in the fall and winter months. .",
            "imageUrl": "https://32lxcujgg9-flywheel.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/butternut-Squash-Blue-Cheese-Pizza-8.jpg",
            "name": "tolulope",
            "title": "Butternut Squash Pizza with Blue Cheese"
        }
    }
}`;
  objectKeys;
  ngOnInit() {

    this.objectKeys = Object.keys;
    this.posts = JSON.parse(this.posts).posts;
    console.log(this.posts);

  }



}
```

**Component**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let post of objectKeys(posts) ">
    <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight waves-light" mdbRippleRadius>
            <img src="{{ posts[post].imageUrl }}" alt="First sample image">
            <a>
                <div class="mask">{{posts[post].body}}</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-epi5rf?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<ng-container *ngIf="post$ | async; let post; else othercontent">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
            <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight waves-light" mdbRippleRadius>
                <img src="{{ post.imageUrl }}" alt="First sample image">
                <a>
                    <div class="mask"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #othercontent>Loading Post...</ng-template>
```

You cant do `*ngFor` with object, hope you read the comments.